# Linking two fields in 2 different nodes created proceduraly

Tags: python, nodes, lighting, nuke

I am creating a nuke node to easily manipulate my different lights in a node. I want to code it so that it doesn't matter how many lights are in any given file, and the code can figure it out and display the necessary tools to modify them. To achieve this, I first identify how many lights are in the file and store that value, which then gets fed to a 'for' cycle to create as many nodes and tools as lights are on the original file. 'tempNumber' is the number assigned to the original Lights on the file, and it helps create and manage all the tools, labeled to match the light they are modifying. It becomes complicated because the names of the nodes generated look like this:

`globals()['expoParent{}'.format(tempNumber)]`

Up to now everything has been working fine but I am stuck trying to link two different Exposure nodes to reflect the same values as the user modifies them. I created this code for that purpose on a separate script:

`par = nuke.nodes.EXPTool(mode = 'Stops', name = 'Parent')`

`chi = nuke.nodes.EXPTool(mode = 'Stops', name = 'Child')`

`par.knob('knobChanged').setValue('chi["red"].setValue(par["red"].value())\nchi["green"].setValue(par["green"].value())\nchi["blue"].setValue(par["blue"].value())')`

This previous bit of code works perfectly, it creates 2 Exposure nodes and it links the Child to the Parent so that any change made to the Parent is then automatically passed along to the Child immediately. Now the problem comes when I try to replace the variables `par` and `chi` with `globals()['expoParent{}'.format(tempNumber)]` and `globals()['expoChild{}'.format(tempNumber)]` . At this point the code stops working and the link is not successful. I have read plenty of people saying that variables should not be created through a for loop but I don't see any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do it with a knobChanged function at all when you can just link the node fields with expressions?

Here's an example that links two grade nodes (Grade1 and Grade2) with Grade1 as the parent. You'll need to have these in your script before running the code. Though you could also create them procedurally.

```
parent = nuke.toNode('Grade1')
child = nuke.toNode('Grade2')

child['multiply'].setExpression('%s.multiply' % parent.name())
```

This is a lot cleaner, and would be represented visually in the node tree too.